# link to table with column variable

Tags: php, sql

I would like to link to the table with the uploader column that has the uploaders name.

```
<a href="?uploader=MM_Username" class="login"><?php echo $_SESSION['MM_Username'];?></a>

<?php 
$subQ2 = ''; 
if(isset($_GET['uploader']) && $_GET['uploader']!='')
{
     $subQ2 = ' WHERE uploader="'.mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace('_', '', $_GET['uploader'])).'"';     
}

function uploader()
{
    if(isset($_GET['uploader']) && $_GET['uploader']!='')
    {
        return $_GET['uploader'];
    }
    else return "uploader";
}

$query_Form = "SELECT * FROM docus".$subQ2.' ORDER BY ID DESC';
$Form = mysql_query($query_Form, $dbconnection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Form = mysql_fetch_assoc($Form);
$totalRows_Form = mysql_num_rows($Form);
?>
```

I'm trying to learn php and sql from video tutorials so this may sound like a dumb question.

Any help is greatly apreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
<?php 
function uploader()
{
    global $dbconnection;

    $return = array('data' => null, 'data_count' => 0);

    if(!empty($_GET['uploader']))
    {
         $data = mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace('_', '', $_GET['uploader']));

         $query_Form = 'SELECT * FROM docus  WHERE uploader="'.trim($data).'" ORDER BY ID DESC';

         $Form = mysql_query($query_Form, $dbconnection) or die(mysql_error());
         $return['data'] = mysql_fetch_assoc($Form);
         $return['data_count'] = mysql_num_rows($Form);
    }

    return $return;
}

$total = upload();

// $row_Form - is now $total['data];
// $totalRows_Form - is now $total['data_count];
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dmitry ! the only thing that doesnt work is this uploader=MM_Username unless i change the MM_Username to the usernem i want, could you tell me what i'm doing wrong ? THANKS !

Comment: When the uploader variable is empty, you will not want to output the data, i'm understand you?

Comment: I edited my answer, hope it the solution that you need

Comment: i get this :  WARNING: MYSQL_QUERY() EXPECTS PARAMETER 2 TO BE RESOURCE, NULL GIVEN IN C:\WAMP\WWW\GARDENSITE\INCLUDES\HEADER.PHP ON LINE 42

Comment: line 42 is this $Form = mysql_query($query_Form, $dbconnection) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: add global $dbconnection to your function